# How to boot from HDD if my laptop has both SSD and HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

My laptop has a 256GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD. I want windows 11 in my SSD and Ubuntu 22.04 in my HDD. I want when I switch on my computer both the OSs should be available to boot from in the boot menu. I have enabled the boot menu from windows 11 but whenever I boot my machine on the boot menu it only shows windows 11. No option for ubuntu is available. I have properly installed Ubuntu on my hdd. I'm just able to boot from my HDD. How can I achieve this

Comment: What brand/model system? Does it matter if grub's boot files are in ESP on SSD  as that is default. You have to add an ESP and manually reinstall grub to have it on HDD. Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator All two  drive systems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu? Same key you used to boot installer.

Comment: I have a HP 15s-gr0012AU. Other than that all ESP stuff have gone over my head. Don't take me wrong but I could not understand it. I know grub as a bootloader of ubuntu.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware and if SSD the firmware. Windows often does that automatically. Most with HP have to go into UEFI settings to change boot order. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings Grub only boots working Windows so fast startup must be off in Windows. ESP - efi system partition, formatted FAT32 with boot,esp flags. Windows & Ubuntu can use same ESP. But when installing to separate drives some minor advantages to having ESP on second drive.